# Fix database encoding issue

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have migrated a legacy database and application to newer machines. The application was built using iso-8859-1.  Some of the records in the database have characters like `’` that need to be replaced with `'`, or I need to figure out a way to display them.

I've solved *most* of the issues with setting the default character set within php.ini and httpd.  However, these fields that have the characters in them are just ignored - they're not in the results from the mysqli queries.

Is there a way to fix this without doing a database dump and find-and-replace?

Comment: It is possible to switch to utf8, where `’` is a valid character (distinct from `'`).  If you want to go that direction, need some more details.  Meanwhile, see "Best practices" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: @RickJames not possible to switch.  It's a legacy app and that was the first thing I tried, caused all sorts of problems.  I've gotten most of the issues with `UPDATE .. REPLACE ..` commands, which was pretty painless.